# Another rebus for yer :D

Tags: rebus

[image]

What two-word phrase is represented here?

Comment: The classic is ECNALG which actually is a common phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a

> Backward phrase?

Because

> I don't think it's needed a reason why, just spell it backwards and it says "**PHRASE**"

Comment: Too fast! Good job!

Comment: I never noticed before that PHRASE is an anagram of SHARPE.

Comment: Is this even a well-known phrase or idiom though? That's usually the point of a rebus... Otherwise you could just create a rebus like HSIF and say the answer is "Backwards fish"... (Not a criticism of the answer, just a comment for discussion...)